# Asymptotics of harmonic series

Tags: asymptotics

> Show that $$ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = \Theta(\ln n) $$

How do I solve this problem?

I tried to to integrate it but I got a weird answer.

Comment: Asked several times on [math.se], e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596621/asymptotic-estimate-of-the-sequence-of-harmonic-series-sum-k-1n-frac1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked repeatedly on [math.se].

Comment: Nice article "The Harmonic Series Diverges Again and Again" https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1065.761&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\frac{1}{i}$ is monotonically decreasing. Then:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} < 1 + \int_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x} \,\mathsf{d}x = 1 + \left[ \ln x  \right]_{x=1}^n = 1+ \ln n \in O(\log n).
$$

Moreover,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} > \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i} > \int_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \,\mathsf{d}x = \left[ \ln x  \right]_{x=1}^{n} = \ln(n) \in \Omega(\log n).
$$